# RxJS Observable Merging

Tags: angular, rxjs

Let's assume I have a REST server with two possible GET requests. 
 
One like this:  `/allItems` and another one: `/{itemId}/picture`. 

 The first returns all stored items on my server as an array (only once), in which each one has an Id. 

For each of them i would like to request their respective picture and match it with them. 
Something like this:

```
this.http.get('/allItems').map(itemArray => {
   itemArray.forEach(item => {
       this.http.get('/' + item.id + '/picture')
                .subscribe(pic => item.pic = pic)
   return itemArray
 }
})
```

At the end i want to return **one** Observable which emits the item-array with their respective pictures mapped, so other functions can access the complete data.

Might be worth mentioning: I'm using Angular/Typescript.

Comment: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: That's it. Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 0):

One approach to this problem can be something like this:-

```
this.http.get('/allItems').pipe(
  mergeMap((itemsArray) => of(itemsArray)),
  mergeMap(item => this.http.get('/' + item.id + '/picture')
    .pipe(
      map(picture => { const a = { 'item': item, 'image': picture }; return a; })
    ),
    toArray()),
).subscribe();  ---> this will give the array of json with item and picture field.
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand from the comments that OP has already found the solution. For those who are wondering, this is how you can use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html), which waits for the Array. forEach() loop to be completed before returning the observable values.

Here is how it could be implemented:

```
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

this.http.get('/allItems').pipe(
  mergeMap(itemArray => {
    const observableList = [];
    itemArray.forEach(item => {
      observableList.push(this.http.get(`/${item.id}/picture`));
    });
    return forkJoin(observableList);
  )}
).subscribe(res => {
  console.log(res);
  // handle the rest here
})
```

Answer (score 0):

@emkay I refactor your code. I think that it looks better. @mortom123 want to replace in object value for the key pic.

```
this.http.get('/allItems')
 .pipe(
  .mergeMap((itemArray) => from(itemArray))
  .mergeMap((item) => this.http.get(`/${item.id}/picture`))
   .pipe(
    map((picture) => (
      {
        ...item,
        pic: picture
      })
 ).subscribe((data) => console.log(data));
```